# terraform output file doesn't have option of status

Tags: python, terraform

I'm trying to get the status check of a newly created instance through terraform output.

I checked for all the possible arguments we can get for output, but I couldn't find any.

Is there a way I can check the health of the newly created instance?  I have subsequent scripts to run if the health check passes.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? It feels like you might be trying to achieve something wider than your question asks for so there might be a better approach than what you're trying.

Comment: if i create a ec2 machine through terraform. i want the status_checks should be displayed using outputs.tf

Comment: Why do you want to see the health of the instance in the outputs?

Comment: based on the status. it should trigger other job to mount the disks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this one of two ways. You can add a [local-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) to your ec2 resource or add a [null_resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/resource.html) with a local-exec provisioner that has a [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#depends_on) on your ec2 resource. Then I would use the AWS CLI to keep checking the status of your instance until the status checks are done. This would require you to make any resources you want to run next also have the depends_on to chain them together as terraform will not be able to figure that out. [Here](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/how-to-handle-unsupported-azure-features-in-terraform) is my blog post where I do something similar for Azure.

The null resource provider:

```
resource "null_resource" "status" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok --instance-ids ${use interpolation here to get id}"
    }
    depends_on = ["ec2 instance"]
}
```

Alternatively, you could execute a python script that uses the Boto API to do the same thing instead of the AWS CLI.

Hope this helps getting you in the correct direction.